# How to Update csv with new records with same ID's in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to Update the pre-existing CSV which is in my local folder with same ID's. Let me elaborate this question.

df1:

```
Item_id  Country  Compay
   1     Germany  sitz.co
   2              likrds.co
   3     Denmark  Axitr.co
   4     Italy
```

this is my df1, I wanted to export this file as CSV in my folder.so i did,

```
df1.to_csv(r'folder_path\df1.csv',index=False)
```

So at this point of time, I have df1 in my folder. Let's say I have df2 with new item_ids and as well as some item_ids which are in df1. I want to append the df2 in the same file, if that file contains similar item_ids it should update the pre-existing records and also append the new item_ids records in to that CSV.

df2:

```
Item_id  Country   Compay
   11    Argentina sitz.co
   2     Russia    likrds.co
   13    Denmark   Axitr.co
   4     Italy     ghrx.co

df2.to_csv(r'folder_path\df1.csv',mode='a',index=False)
```

when I ran the above code, I CSV is getting appended with the duplicate records but I need the records to be updated with the new one based on Item ID.

Desired_csv:

```
Item_id  Country   Compay
   1     Germany   sitz.co
   2     Russia    likrds.co
   3     Denmark   Axitr.co
   4     Italy     ghrx.co
   11    Argentina sitz.co
   13    Denmark   Axitr.co
```

Comment: are there going to be more files in your folder? do you want to update the second last dataframe with the last always or just replace the nulls? example if id 2 is not null in the first dataframe would your expected output be same? Also how many files (hypothetically) can there be in the folder and of what size?

Comment: There will be only one file in that folder, but there will be more and more file will come & I wanna update the pre-existing records. Order doesn't matter. It would be great if it is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution using `glob` and `groupby+last`:

```
import glob
list_of_files = glob.glob(r'folder_path\*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(i) for i in list_of_files]
output = pd.concat(dfs).groupby("Item_id",as_index=False).last()
```

---

```
   Item_id    Country     Compay
0        1    Germany    sitz.co
1        2     Russia  likrds.co
2        3    Denmark   Axitr.co
3        4      Italy    ghrx.co
4       11  Argentina    sitz.co
5       13    Denmark   Axitr.co
```

If you have just 2 dataframes:

```
l = [df1,df2]
output = pd.concat(l).groupby("Item_id",as_index=False).last()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the index of `df1` and `df2` as `Item_id` then use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df2.set_index('Item_id')\
        .combine_first(df1.set_index('Item_id')).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df)
   Item_id    Country     Compay
0        1    Germany    sitz.co
1        2     Russia  likrds.co
2        3    Denmark   Axitr.co
3        4      Italy    ghrx.co
4       11  Argentina    sitz.co
5       13    Denmark   Axitr.co
```